# Make button have active state on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a button have a class .active added to it, to which i have attached CSS styles. I am trying to do this using jQuery.

My HTML is as follows:

```
    <ul class="num-list num-list-top">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
```

My jQuery is as follows:

```
    $('.num-list-top li').click(function() {
        $(".num-list-top").toggleClass("active");
    });
```

Right now what the code does is give all the li list items a class of active. I want only the li item that is clicked to have the active class toggled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.num-list-top li').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
```

Becouse using `this` will get the li clicked

Comment: ah.. thats it. thanks. I will accept it as soon as stackoverflow allows me.